# JSOUP parse for android force closes

Tags: android, parsing, web-scraping, jsoup, forceclose

I am trying to use JSOUP to get the menu data from a website (http://hdh.ucsd.edu/mobile/dining/locationdetails.aspx?l=11) but whenever I try to fetch the links, my android app crashes. What is the reason? This is the code I have

```
public class SixthFragment extends Fragment {

String url = "http://hdh.ucsd.edu/mobile/dining/locationdetails.aspx?l=11";
ProgressDialog mProgressDialog;
String MENU;
String HOURS;
TextView textview;

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_sixth, container, false);
    textview = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.textView10);

    new JSOUP().execute();
    return rootView;

}

public class JSOUP extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>{
    ProgressDialog dialog;

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute(){
        super.onPreExecute();
        dialog = new ProgressDialog(getActivity());
        dialog.setMessage("loading...");
        dialog.show();

    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params){
        try{

            Document document = Jsoup.connect(url).get();
            Elements elements = document.select("a[href]");
            //HOURS = elements.text();
            System.out.println(elements.size());
            for(int i = 0; i<elements.size(); i++){

                MENU += "\n" + elements.get(i).text();
                System.out.println(i);

            }

        }

        catch (Exception e){

        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result){
        dialog.dismiss();

        textview.setText(MENU);
        super.onPostExecute(result);
    }

}

}
```

And my error shows up as this

```
11-28 13:48:59.175 23230-23230/com.lamdevs.tritonbites E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.lamdevs.tritonbites, PID: 23230
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.TextView.setText(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null object reference
at com.lamdevs.tritonbites.fragments.SixthFragment$JSOUP.onPostExecute(SixthFragment.java:82)
at com.lamdevs.tritonbites.fragments.SixthFragment$JSOUP.onPostExecute(SixthFragment.java:43)
at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:632)
at android.os.AsyncTask.access$600(AsyncTask.java:177)
at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:645)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
```

Which I don't understand because elements has a size of 61 when I output the size of elements. Also, is there a way to get the breakfast, lunch, and dinner separately? Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please post your layout XML `R.layout.fragment_sixth`. Probably you're referring to a wrong id, which causes de `NullPointerException`.

---

To get each "Breakfast", "Lunch" and "Dinner" separately, you can simply iterate through the last three `<div>` tags inside the HTML element with id `MainContent_divDailySpecials` (I did find that id looking at the website DOM structure through Chrome Developer Tools inspector).

So, as a start, simply grab that element with

```
Document document = Jsoup.connect(url).get();
Element parentDiv = document.getElementById("MainContent_divDailySpecials");
```

and from there on you can iterate backwards to get the last three children of that `div`. (Please keep in mind that if, in any point in time, the structure of that page changes your code will break).

Comment: Yes I figured out the NullPointerException I named the textview wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the error log you attached ..

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 
'void android.widget.TextView.setText(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null object reference
at com.lamdevs.tritonbites.fragments.SixthFragment$JSOUP.onPostExecute(SixthFragment.java:82)
```

It talks about a `NullPointerException` on a `TextView` in `SixthFragment` Line 82 i.e. `textview.setText(MENU);`

The `textview` is initialized (`textview = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.textView10);`) which looks okay.

So, make sure you have a `TextView` with id `textView10` in your layout `fragment_sixth`.